# Faster multiple criteria search/filter excel

Tags: vba, excel

Hi guys I made the code below to search for multiple text in a given column. The problem is that it is very slow. Do guys know any other ways to perform it faster?

For example give the array ('foo', 'bar'), The code should iterate on a column and match/filter only the rows that have both texts in any given order.

```
Sub aTest()
ScreenUpdating = False

Dim selectedRange As Range, cell As Range

Dim searchValues() As String

searchValues = Split(ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1).Value)

Set selectedRange = Range("A4:A40000")

Dim element As Variant

For Each cell In selectedRange
    If cell.Value = "" Then
        Exit For
    Else
        For Each element In searchValues
            If Not InStr(1, cell.Value, element) Then
                cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next element
    End If
Next cell

ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I was using it as a filter. copied and pasted the following code with a few modifications. But then I was not able to make the changes to match multiple strings.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim iFilterColumn As Integer
    Dim rFilter As Range
    Dim sCriteria As String
    On Error Resume Next
    With Target
        Set rFilter = .Parent.AutoFilter.Range
        iFilterColumn = .Column + 1 - rFilter.Columns(1).Column
        If Intersect(Target, Range("rCriteria")) Is Nothing Then GoTo Terminator
        Select Case Left(.Value, 1)
        Case ">", "<"
            sCriteria = .Value
        Case Else
            sCriteria = "=*" & .Value & "*"
        End Select
        If sCriteria = "=" Then
            .Parent.Range(rFilter.Address).AutoFilter Field:=iFilterColumn
        Else
            .Parent.Range(rFilter.Address).AutoFilter Field:=iFilterColumn, Criteria1:=sCriteria
        End If
    End With
Terminator:
    Set rFilter = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Look at the `Range.Find` function..

Comment: Hi, try advanced filter. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841242.aspx. Also, using a SQL statement gives fast results too, may or may not be useful here.

Comment: Can you not use the filter?

Comment: Edited to explain the filter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this:

```
Set selectedRange = Range("A4:A40000")
```

It's because the size is not defined properly, the following should limit to the right long

```
Set selectedRange = Range("A4:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
```

If it doesn't affect, I always use these codes to speed up Excel (Instead of only ScreenUpdating alone).

```
Sub ExcelNormal()
        With Excel.Application
        .Cursor = xlDefault
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .StatusBar = False
        End With
End Sub
Sub ExcelBusy()
        With Excel.Application
        .Cursor = xlWait
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .StatusBar = False
        End With
End Sub
```

Note: In the future Probably [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be better place to post.